# JSON decode in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, json, cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I want the JSON data that is receiving in my app to be decoded and stored into MySQL database.

This is an Android application made using Phonegap.

Here is the application code :

```
function onNotification(e) {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> RECEIVED:' + e.event + '</li>');

                switch( e.event )
                {
                    case 'registered':
                    if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
                    {
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>REGISTERED -> REGID:' + e.regid + "</li>");
                        console.log("regID = " + e.regid);
                        $("#pp").click(function(){
    tokenHandler(e.regid);
});
                    }
                    break;

                    case 'message':
                        if (e.foreground)
                        {
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--INLINE NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
        var soundfile = e.soundname || e.payload.sound;
        var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/"+ soundfile);
        my_media.play();
                        }
                        else
                        {   
                        if (e.coldstart)
    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--COLDSTART NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                        else
    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                        }
    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSG: ' + e.payload.message + '</li>');

                        //android only
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSGCNT: ' + e.payload.msgcnt + '</li>');
                        //amazon-fireos only
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> TIMESTAMP: ' + e.payload.timeStamp + '</li>');
                    break;

                    case 'error':
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>ERROR -> MSG:' + e.msg + '</li>');
                    break;

                    default:
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> Unknown, an event was received and we do not know what it is</li>');
                    break;
                }
            }
```

e.payload.message contains the message to be decoded.
Here is the server side code :

```
 <?php

    class GCMPushMessage {
        var $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
        var $serverApiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        var $devices = 0;


        function GCMPushMessage(){
            //$this->serverApiKey = $apiKeyIn;
        }


        function setDevices($deviceIds){

            if(is_array($deviceIds)){
                $this->devices = $deviceIds;
            } else 
    {
                $this->devices = array($deviceIds);
            }

        }


        /*
            Send the message to the device
            @param $message The message to send
            @param $data Array of data to accompany the message
        */
        function send($message, $data = false){
            //echo $this->serverApiKey.$this->devices[0];
            if(!is_array($this->devices) || count($this->devices) == 0){
                $this->error("No devices set");
            }

            if(strlen($this->serverApiKey) < 8){
                $this->error("Server API Key not set");
            }

            $fields = array(
                'registration_ids'  => $this->devices,
                'data'              => array( "message" => $message ),
            );

            if(is_array($data)){
                foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                    $fields['data'][$key] = $value;
            }
            }
            $headers = array( 
                'Authorization: key=' . $this->serverApiKey,
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            );
            // Open connection
            $ch = curl_init();

            // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url );

            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );

            // Avoids problem with https certificate
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

            // Execute post
            $result = curl_exec($ch);

            // Close connection
            curl_close($ch);

            return $result;
        }


        function error($msg){
            echo "Android send notification failed with error:";
            echo "\t" . $msg;
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    $query="select * from prescription where id=".$id;
    $results1=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $rs1=mysql_fetch_assoc($results1);
    $mid=$rs1['med_id'];
    $query="select * from medicine where mid=".$rs1['med_id'];
    $results2=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $diagnosis=$_POST['diagnosis'];
        $instructions=$_POST['instructions'];
        $query=mysql_query("update prescription set diagnosis='".$diagnosis."' , instructions='".$instructions."' where id=".$id);
        $rc=mysql_num_rows($results2);
        $i=1;
        $query="delete from medicine where mid=".$mid;
        $results3=mysql_query($query);
        while($i<=$rc)
        {
            $medicine=' ';
            $tm1=$tm2=$tm3=0;
            $medicine=$_POST['old_'.$i];
            $tm='';
            if(isset($_POST['old_1_'.$i]))
                {$tm1=1;}
            if(isset($_POST['old_2_'.$i]))
                {$tm2=1;}
            if(isset($_POST['old_3_'.$i]))
                {$tm3=1;}
            $dosage=$_POST['old_dosage_'.$i];
            $str="insert into medicine values('$mid','$dosage','$medicine','$tm1','$tm2','$tm3')";
            $res=@mysql_query($str)or die(mysql_error());
            $i++;
        }
        $nf=$_POST['nf'];
        $i=1;
        while($i<=$nf)
            {
            $medicine=' ';
            $tm1=$tm2=$tm3=0;
            $medicine=$_POST['medicine_'.$i];
            $tm='';
            if(isset($_POST['tm_1_'.$i]))
                {$tm1=1;}
            if(isset($_POST['tm_2_'.$i]))
                {$tm2=1;}
            if(isset($_POST['tm_3_'.$i]))
                {$tm3=1;}
            $dosage=$_POST['dosage_'.$i];
            $str="insert into medicine values('$mid','$dosage','$medicine','$tm1','$tm2','$tm3')";
            $res=@mysql_query($str)or die(mysql_error());
            $i++;
        }
    $gcpm = new GCMPushMessage();
    $sql=mysql_query("select token from device where id=".$id);
    $rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
    $gcpm->setDevices($rs['token']);
    $query1=mysql_query("select * from medicine,prescription where med_id=mid and id=".$id);
    while($rs1=mysql_fetch_assoc($query1))
    {
    $rows[]['tm_1']=$rs['tm_1'];
    $rows[]['tm_2']=$rs['tm_2'];
    $rows[]['tm_2']=$rs['tm_3'];
    $rows[]['diagnosis']=$rs['diagnosis'];
    $rows[]['instructions']=$rs['instructions'];
    $rows[]['medicine_name']=$rs['medicine_name'];
    $rows[]['dosage']=$rs['dosage'];
    }
    $response = $gcpm->send($message, $rows);
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql );
    }
```

I tried to parse the JSON but failed. Any idea?

Comment: Only post the neccesary code, this is to much code.

Comment: what error message you got?

Comment: Message type was undefined.